# Qt: get text from button in QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qpushbutton

I have QTableWidget in my Qt application, and I add buttons to it like that:

```
QPushButton *startButton = new QPushButton("start");
ui->tableWidget_tvConnection->setCellWidget(row, col, startButton);
connect(startButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(startButtonPressed()));
```

And when it is pressed I need to get text from it, so I tried this:

```
void MainWindow::startButtonPressed()
{
    ...
    QPushButton *button = ui->tableWidget_tvConnection->cellWidget(row, col);
    qDebug() << button->text();
}
```

But compiler doesn't allow me to convert from QWidget* to QPushButton*:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'QWidget*' to 'QPushButton*' [-fpermissive]
```

So Is it even possible to get text from button inside QTableWidget?
If it isn't I have another way how to handle this in my application, but this would be really nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `QWidget`, so you should cast it to `QPushButton`. After that, you will be able to use this as a normal `pushbutton`.  Try this:

```
QPushButton *button = qobject_cast<QPushButton *>(ui->tableWidget_tvConnection->cellWidget(row, col));

if(button) {
    //success
} else {
    //bad
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо :)